# Protect virtual directory (IIS) behind ASP.NET Core web API

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core, web-config

My goal is to protect a static folder (with docs `html` content) from public access. The authentication should take place in an external API (.net core) which is hosted by the same `IIS` instance.

My first attempt is to intercept the `Request` and look for a specific path. In case of a unauthicated user, he is redirected to the login page.

```
app.UseAuthentication();

app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
{
    if (!ctx.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && 
         ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(docsPath))
    {
        await ctx.ChallengeAsync();
        return;
    }
    await next.Invoke();
});

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Account}/{action=Login}/{id?}");
});
```

But the request is handled first by IIS and routed to the docs without touching the `Middleware`.
Are there any ways to accomplish the correct behavior?

Hint: The docs should **not** go into `wwwroot` or become a part of the `API` project.

Comment: What does the rest of your setup look like ? Are you using `app.UseStaticFiles()`?

Comment: My code is updated

Comment: as this is an IIS question, you might want to post your web.config as well

Comment: My `web.config` is the default one, unchanged. For my application and the virtual directory. No redirects. No rules.

Answer (score 0):

You problem is that Authentication middleware handles only controllers with `Authorize` attribute.
The [recommended way for .Net Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x) is to use the ordinary approach:

> To serve files based on authorization: Store them outside of wwwroot
>   and any directory accessible to the static file middleware and Serve
>   them via an action method to which authorization is applied. Return a
>   FileResult object:

```
[Authorize]
public IActionResult BannerImage()
{
    var file = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), 
                            "MyStaticFiles", "images", "banner1.svg");

    return PhysicalFile(file, "image/svg+xml");
}
```

However if, as you say, your docs directory is outside the API project at all, you may try to rely on IIS Authentication by placing a custom web.config:

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```